# Show $z_1/z_2 \in \{x+y \sqrt{5} \mid x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Tags: group-theory

I just started a Math course at my college in Europe. Now, I've been staring at this assignment for over an hour - and I'm really stuck.

The task is to assume $z_1$ and $z_2$ are elements of $M$, where

$$M=\left\{{x+y\sqrt{5}\mid x,y \in \mathbb{Q}}\right\}$$
I've shown that $${z_{1}}\cdot z_{2}=\\
(x_1+ y_1\sqrt{5})\cdot (x_2+ y_2\sqrt{5})\\
x_1 x_{2}+x_{1}y_2\sqrt{5}+y_1\sqrt{5}x_2+y_1 \sqrt{5} y_2\sqrt{5}\\
x_1x_2+x_1 y_2\sqrt{5}+y_1\sqrt5x_2+5y_1y_2\\
(x_1x_2+5y_1y_2)+(x_1y_2+y_1 x_2)\sqrt{5}\ \in M$$

Now, I just do not understand the division. Could anybody walk me through it. I would be overjoyed! Thank you, all :)

EDIT 1: I'm terribly sorry for the extremely cryptic question. My question is
**taken that I have muliplied the two $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ correctly - how would I go around dividing them?**

EDIT 2 (Solution 1):

$${{x_{1}x_{2}-5y_{1}y_{2}}\over{x_{2}^{2}-5y_{2}^{2}}}+{{y_{1}x_{2}-x_{1}y_{2}}\over{x_{2}^{2}-5y_{2}^{2}}}\sqrt{5} \in M$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{x_1 + y_1 \sqrt{5}}{x_2 + y_2 \sqrt{5}} = \frac{(x_1 + y_1 \sqrt{5})\cdot(x_2 - y_2 \sqrt{5})}{(x_2 + y_2 \sqrt{5})\cdot(x_2 - y_2 \sqrt{5})}$$

and calculate as you did before.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much! Would you mind taking a look at my edit. I wasn't able to add TeX to the reply :) Thank you so much!!

Comment: That looks good!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{1}{x+y\sqrt{5}}=\frac{x-y\sqrt{5}}{x^2-5y^2}.$$